# Chromecast CustomReceiver with MetaData

Tags: chromecast

We use a CustomReceiver in our Chromecast Receiver Application with an own Videoplayer solution for various reasons. Therefore, we dont use LoadRequests or MediaManager at all.
This is working very good, no issues so far. But what is missing are the MetaData, that are visible in the Chrome Extension and/or android Screen. I guess, somehow, we should broadcast some MediaInfo Events with Metadata, but due to the fact, that this is completely handled by MediaManager normally, its very unclear to me, how to make these informations available without the usage of MediaManger. 
Does anyone has informations or a running sample of such a case?

Thanks!
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get some background on chromecast [messages](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#messages)

MediaInfo excerpt can be included in a custom namespace message reserved by you to tell your reciever about the item playing.

A sample message:

```
{"requestId":0,"status":{"applications":[{"appId":"E4F","displayName":"rr_test_chromecast","namespaces":[{"name":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.player.message"},{"name":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media"}],"sessionId":"7CD0C2DE-B05E-8115-1387-F9147DFD9C89","statusText":"Now Casting: is looks like it's sprin","transportId":"web-1"}],"volume":{"level":1.0,"muted":false}},"type":"RECEIVER_STATUS"}
```

[A library](https://github.com/vincentbernat/nodecastor/blob/master/lib/cast_channel.proto) that includes a focus on chromecast message protocols